# Share Button using ShareActionProvider Not Responsive

Tags: java, android, share

In my app I am trying to add a share button to do the same function as this one:
http://postimg.org/image/pcpg9bdn7/ (I need more rep to post images)

I got the Share button to show up, but it does not respond when I click on it. I am using 4.4 API.
Here is my button in XML in the menu layout file

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
          android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
          android:title="Share"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

This works but I think it is the Java that is broken. Here is my OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_share_menu, menu);
        provider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share)
                .getActionProvider();
        return true;
    }
```

Finally here is the code in onOptionsItemSelected:

```
case R.id.menu_item_share:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a message for you");
                provider.setShareIntent(intent);
                break;
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be awesome!!!!

Answer (score 1):

you call `setShareIntent` when the menu item is selected, but it can't be selected because there is no `Intent` set.

try calling `setShareIntent` earlier, for example in `onCreateOptionsMenu` or when the data is ready.

Comment: That would require moving everything to OnCreateOptions menu, or it would og null.......

Comment: if the data is ready when `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called you can do it there, otherwise, call `setShareIntent` when your data is ready (provider is already initialized at this point)

Comment: So initialize the Intent in there too? What is actually calling the intent to open?

Comment: `ShareProvider` handles everything, you just need to `setShareIntent` first